# Find a line by using filereader in perl

Tags: perl, filereader, param

I created a text-box .I want to control what the user writes in the text-box by reading a text file and comparing each line with the text using Perl. In my code I filled to `param('text')`

```
open(DATA, "<baba.txt") or die "Couldn't open file file.txt, $!";
while(<DATA>)
{
    if($_=~param('text'))
    {
        print $_;
    }   
}
```

I have no problem while reading the file but i couldn't handle the matches. It returned nothing.

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

The right side of the =~ operator needs to be a regular expression.

See [this site](http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/Perl/matching.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (<DATA>)
{
  chomp;
  if (param('text') =~ /\Q$_/)
  {
      print $_;
  }   
}
```

Comment: actually, its not enough for my situation because user post mark 1990 
and i want to control can they write  1990.

Comment: @user3297904 post some lines from file, and user input examples.

Comment: they will post mark 1990 , steve 1890 and in my text file just write 1990 1890 1991 in every line just has one date

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $text = <<END;
This is just a BU.NCH of text
in a here document that will
be used for some matching in
just a little bit.
END

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    if ( $text =~ /\b\Q$_\E\b/i ) {
        print $_, "\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
this
some
bu.nch
a
hello
world
```

Output:

```
this
some
bu.nch
a
```

Before attempting to match a word read from a file, you need to `chomp` it, to remove the record separator (if any), which is usually `\n`.  There are also a few other items for you to consider:

1. Whether you want a case-insensitive match
2. Escaping any meta-characters in your words which may be present
3. Forcing word borders to prevent an in-string match.

Item (1) above is achieved by using the `/i` modifier.  Item (2) is done by enclosing the 'word' in the regex like this: `\Q$_\E` (`\Q`uote-meta; `\E`nd Quote-meta).  And the last uses `\b`: `\b\Q$_\E\b`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
my $text = param('text');

open(DATA, "<baba.txt") or die "Couldn't open file file.txt, $!";
while(<DATA>)
{
    if($_=~ /$text/ )
    {
        print $_;
    }   
}
```

because this -> $_=~param('text') not regexp search